# Java Oracle SQL missing SELECT keyword

Tags: sql

I have this query, can't find the error that gives missing SELECT keyword.

dbverbinding is an object which has the method to insert to the database. This has worked for other insert query. However this query doesn't work.

```
        dbverbinding.insertupdatedelete("INSERT INTO schedule ('date', employee_id, daypart) "
            + "VALUES('"+datum+"', '"+ID+"', '"+daypart+"')");
```

EDIT: 
I was trying with hardcoded values, nevertheless this doesn't work.

```
        dbverbinding.insertupdatedelete("INSERT INTO schedule ('date', employee_id, daypart) "
            + "VALUES('29-05-14', 1, 'avond')");
```

Comment: 'date' should be "date" I think, you'll need to escape the double-quotes.

Comment: Also, another bit of critique, you should use bind variables generally speaking.  Concatenating SQL is prone to SQL injection attacks and is not a good practice.

Comment: What is dbverbinding? what datatypes do you database columns have? Can you provide some more information please?

Comment: Yes, date in single quotes is obviously the error, though the error message could be more precise here ;-) Moreover, you shouldn't pass the date as a string, so you don't depend on current database settings. Better use `"to_date('"+datum+"','dd-mm-yy'), ...`.